# Header Content Type image-png and transparent output

Tags: php, header, gd

is there a way to create transparent image when we are using  `header("Content-Type: image/png")`?

```
<?php

    $path = "image.png";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

**edit :**
output -> [image]

Comment: Yes, this should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: yep!but isn't transparent

Comment: OK, see my answer with code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it should work automatically but it seems you have to use `imagealphablending()` and `imagesavealpha()`:

```
$path = "image.png";
$image = imagecreatefrompng($path);

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```